# Pass input value from one form to hidden field of another using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to Pass `input` value from one `form` to the `hidden` field of another using `jquery` or `javascript`. Here `id="q1"` from form1 should pass to `id="q2"` of form2 on `submit`.

```
<form name="form1">
    <input type="text" value="" name="QUANTITY" id="q1">
</form>

<form name="form2">
    <input type="text"  value="" name="Size" id="s1">
    <input type="text"  value="" name="Height" id="h1">
    <input type="hidden" name="QUANTITY" ID="q2" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#q1').on('blur', function() {
$('#q2').val($(this).val())
});
 })
</script>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submit" >  
</form>
```

Comment: You should show your effort what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Instead before `submit` it will be better value transfer during `onblur` it will be ensure value available on `submit`. Try following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#q1').on('blur', function() {
    $('#q2').val($(this).val())
    });
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I think it is working fine, can you show where and how you added in js?

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the answer. Added this before submit but did not work. Please note the Quantity is already added as 1 in form1. That is mostly not changed. I am not aware of jquery. Can you describe in more detail.

Comment: I updated the answer and let me know if is not working for you.

Comment: QTY= request.form("QUANTITY")  
 response.write(QTY)

Comment: it gives no value on the next page.

Comment: I'm little bit confuse actually what you want. Your question was pass value from one from to other from in hidden field and I did it I can see when submitting it is sending like "?Size=&Height=&QUANTITY=fsadfdsafads&submit=SUBMIT" but now asking to get value in other page?

Comment: Actually all form values are passed to the next page to be used in asp script. But no value of quantity is passed by form submit.